# Discworld's Death letting Granny Weatherwax win in a card game over a child's life

Tags: story-identification, discworld, death

I once read that in one of the Discworld novels, Granny Weatherwax is playing cards against Death over the life of a small child, and Death deliberately let her win. If I recall correctly she says: "I have 4 kings" and he replies "Oh, I have only 4 ones" referring to Aces which beat kings, but he pretends that her hand beats his, thus sparing the child's life.

Which of the Discworld novels contains this and can you quote or bring an excerpt of that scene?

Comment: "Aces low" is a perfectly valid way of playing poker, it's just far less common than "aces high".

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That's from *Maskerade*; Granny is playing for the life of a child.

> Granny sat back.
>
> "Then I challenge you to a game. That's traditional. That's *allowed*."
>
> Death was silent for a moment.
>
> THIS IS TRUE.
>
> "Good."
>
> CHALLENGING ME BY MEANS OF A GAME IS ALLOWABLE.
>
> "Yes."
>
> HOWEVER... YOU UNDERSTAND THAT TO WIN ALL YOU MUST GAMBLE ALL?
>
> "Double or quits? Yes, I know."
>
> BUT NOT CHESS.
>
> "Can't abide chess."
>
> OR CRIPPLE MR ONION. I'VE NEVER BEEN ABLE TO UNDERSTAND THE RULES.
>
> "Very well. How about one hand of poker? Five cards each, no draws? Sudden death, as they say."
>
> Death thought about this, too.
>
> YOU KNOW THIS FAMILY?
>
> No.
>
> THEN WHY?
>
> "Are we talking or are we playing?"
>
> OH, VERY WELL.
>
> Granny picked up the pack of cards and shuffled it, not looking at her hands, and smiling at Death all the time. She dealt five cards each, and reached down...
>
> A bony hand grasped hers.
>
> BUT *FIRST*, MISTRESS WEATHERWAX—WE WILL EXCHANGE CARDS.
>
> He picked up the two piles and transposed them, and then nodded at Granny.
>
> MADAM?
>
> Granny looked at her cards, and threw them down.
>
> **FOUR QUEENS. HMM. THAT IS VERY HIGH.**
>
> Death looked down at his cards, and then up into Granny's steady, blue-eyed gaze.
>
> Neither moved for some time.
>
> Then Death laid the hand on the table.
>
> **I LOSE, he said. ALL I HAVE IS FOUR ONES.**
>
> He looked back into Granny's eyes for a moment. There was a blue glow in the depth of his eye sockets. Maybe, for the merest fraction of a second, barely noticeable even to the closest observation, one winked off.
>
> Granny nodded, and extended a hand.
>
> She prided herself on the ability to judge people by their gaze and their handshake, which in this case was a rather chilly one.

Comment: So she cheated, Death let her know he knew she cheated, and let her win anyway. Nice.

Comment: Can somebody please explain the rules and the joke?

Comment: @Michael The game is poker - 5 card draw specifically, with no further draws. Essentially, each player draws a hand of five cards, and whoever has the best hand (google poker hands) wins.

In this instance, Granny Weatherwax cheats and deals herself 4 aces, and Death 4 queens. Death knows this and swaps their hands, nullifying the cheat and giving himself 4 aces, a winning hand.

In poker, aces are typically "high"; the highest value card. However, they can also be interpreted as 1; the lowest value. Death opts to do this, feigning ignorance, making his hand worth less than 4 queens.

Comment: So the player who plays the card can decide if a 1 is highest value or lowest value?

Comment: @Michael It depends.   In most casinos and professional games the "Cards Talk", which means that even if a player misdeclares their hand (say 4 Aces as 4 Ones), the house would rule them as 4 Aces when the cards are shown.  However, in home games, it is often the rules that "Players Talk" which means that if you under-declare your hand, that's on you.  Since it was a home game, and the cards were never shown, it appears that Death's under-declaration of his own hand would stand.

Comment: (However, even if the "cards talk", Death could have just not declared and thrown his cards in without showing them, conceding the hand.  I assume that the Terry Pratchett thought that this would have been less effective story-telling than the way that he wrote it.)

Comment: Thanks. Damn, Terry Pratchett always requires a ton of background knowledge. Half the time you’d need a separate column in the books which explains all the subtle jokes.

Comment: @JackAidley She *possibly* cheated when she dealt.  He *possibly* cheated by changing the rules mid-game.  And, with the formality of "playing a game for the child's life" established and out of the way, Death was in a position to **decide** the outcome by playing ignorant or not.  It's all undertones, hidden meanings, and mutual respect.

Comment: Headology. Granny knows that Death knows that Granny knows that Death knows it's for a child.

Comment: @Michael I'm guessing you're not from the UK :) They're blatantly obvious to Brits!

Comment: @Michael The Annotated Pratchett File at https://www.lspace.org/books/apf/ may be exactly what you're looking for. It doesn't have everything, and it doesn't have some of the later books, but it's got a lot of the references down. There may be a more complete version out there somewhere, but I don't know where. The TVTropes page for each book might also be a good place to pick up references, but it will also suck up all of your time.